# Trigger for rows where specific column was changed

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, triggers

I would like to find a way in SQL Server, how to update rows where some specific property has changed. Simple example, I want set `Flag = True` in all rows, where `KeyProperty` was changed. I have created SQL Trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER testTrigger
ON table
AFTER UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
  IF(UPDATE(KeyProperty))
  BEGIN
    UPDATE table
    SET Flag = True
    WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM inserted WHERE inserted.Id = table.Id)
  END
END
GO
```

But from the results I assume, `UPDATE(KeyProperty)` looks, if there is at least one row, where `KeyProperty` was updated. So if I have initial table:

| Id | KeyProperty | OtherProperty | Flag |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 | red | False |
| 2 | 200 | blue | False |
| 3 | 300 | black | False |

Update looks like:

| Id | KeyProperty | OtherProperty | Flag |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | **1000** | red | **True** |
| 2 | 200 | blue | False |
| 3 | 300 | **white** | **True** |

So even the Flag in the third row is updated, because there was another update and the row occurs in the `inserted` logical table.

Is there a way how to match row from `inserted` table together with `UPDATE()` condition on that specific row? Putting the condition to WHERE statement made the same result.

Comment: You'd need to `JOIN` the `inserted` and `deleted` pseudo tables and see if the values differ (don't forget to handle `NULL`s too).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to compare the `inserted` and `deleted` tables, joining by primary key, and verify the results are different.

Note that the `UPDATE()` function only tells you if the column was present in the `UPDATE`, not if the value actually changed.

```
CREATE TRIGGER testTrigger
ON table
AFTER UPDATE
AS

  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  IF(UPDATE(KeyProperty))
  BEGIN
    UPDATE t
    SET Flag = True
    FROM (
        SELECT i.Id, i.KeyProperty
        FROM inserted i
        EXCEPT
        SELECT d.Id, d.KeyProperty
        FROM deleted d
    ) i
    JOIN table t ON t.Id = i.Id
  END

GO
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Thanks a lot!